# Most Efficient way to calculate Frequency of values in a Python list?

Tags: python, list, frequency

I am looking for a fast and efficient way to calculate the frequency of `list` items in python:

```
list = ['a','b','a','b', ......]
```

I want a frequency counter which would give me an output like this:

```
 [ ('a', 10),('b', 8) ...]
```

The items should be arranged in descending order of frequency as shown above.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Python2.7+

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> L=['a','b','a','b']
>>> print(Counter(L))
Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2})
>>> print(Counter(L).items())
dict_items([('a', 2), ('b', 2)])
```

python2.5/2.6

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> L=['a','b','a','b']
>>> d=defaultdict(int)
>>> for item in L:
>>>     d[item]+=1
>>>     
>>> print d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 2, 'b': 2})
>>> print d.items()
[('a', 2), ('b', 2)]
```

Comment: Any solution for Python 2.5? I am using this with Google App Engine

Comment: Sure, you can use defaultdict. I will add to my answer

Comment: Thanks for the really quick reply. Appreciate it.

Comment: `Counter` is not the most efficient way; see performance comparison http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522152/python-is-a-dictionary-slow-to-find-frequency-of-each-character

Comment: [this](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/data-structures/0.1.2#bag) could be interesting too, it says counting is O(1) ...