# Unicode support in C++0x

Tags: c++, unicode, stream, c++11

I'm trying to use new unicode characters in C++0x.
So I wrote sample code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::u32string str = U"Hello World";

    std::basic_ofstream<char32_t> fout("output.txt");

    fout<<str;  
    return 0;
}
```

But after executing this program I'm getting empty output.txt file. So why it's not printing Hello World?

Also is there something like a `cout` and `cin` already defined for these types, or `stdin` and `stdout` doesn't support Unicode?

Edit: I'm using g++ and Linux.

EDIT:**АТТЕNTION. I have discovered, that standard committee dismissed  Unicode streams  from C++0x. So previously accepted answer is not correct anymore. For more information see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704585/unicode-support-in-c0x/5666573#5666573)!**

Comment: Is the file empty because it has 0 bytes, or is it empty because your text editor doesn't show any printable characters?

Comment: what gcc version are you using?

Comment: @ssmir I'm using 4.4.3-1ubuntu1 (which comes with ubuntu 10.04). You think problem is in version?

Answer (score 6):

Unicode string literals support [began](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) in GCC 4.5. Maybe that's the problem.

**[edit]**

After some digging I've found that streams for this new unicode literals are described in [N2035](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2035.pdf) and it was [included](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2870.html) in a draft of the standard. According to this document you need `u32ofstream` to output you string but this class is absent in GCC 4.5 C++0x library.

As a workaround you can use ordinary fstream:

```
std::ofstream fout2("output2.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
fout2.write((const char *)str.c_str(), str.size() * 4);
```

This way I've output your string in UTF-32LE on my Intel machine (which is little-endian).

**[edit]**

I was a little bit wrong about the status of `u32ofstream`: according to the [latest draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) on the The C++ Standards Committee's [web site](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/) you have to use `std::basic_ofstream<char32_t>` as you did. This class would use `codecvt<char32_t,char,typename traits::state_type>` class (see end of §27.9.1.1) which has to be implemented in the standard library (search `codecvt<char32_t` in the document), but it's not available in GCC 4.5.

Comment: I'm running gcc 4.5.2 and getting the same result as the OP :(

Comment: According to Grigory Javadyan it's not a problem. :(

Comment: I have discovered, that streams support was removed from C++0x. For more info see my answer. Please correct your answer. it's not correct (up to date anymore) anymore.

Answer (score 3):

**In new C++ standard there will not be  Unicode streams.**

As @ssmir mentioned, standard committee was going to add stream support for Unicode in C++0x. However in the feature editions committee decided to remove stream support for Unicode. For more information see this [link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2238.html).

It seams like the only way to output Unicode string is to convert it to ASCII string with  [codecvt](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/codecvt/) .

Comment: Huh? Where did ssmir imply that? Your link is to a 4-year-old paper.

Comment: The standard contains Unicode streams at least in the latest draft. See my edited answer.

Comment: exactly what answer? how?  I need to use something like cout but I have a u32string I need to output. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11 shows me how to make unicode strings, and I looked inside the gcc string headers to find u32string.

Answer (score 1):

When creating, the stream tries to obtain a 'codecvt' from the global locale, but fails to get one because the only standard codecvt's are for char and wchar_t.
As a result, _M_codecvt member of the stream object is NULL.
Later, during the attempt to output, your code throws an exception (not visible to user) in facet checking function in basic_ios.h, because the facet is initialized from _M_codecvt.

Add a facet to the local associated with the stream to do the conversion from char32_t to the correct output.
Imbue the stream with a locale containing a codecvt of the right type.

Comment: c++ code from my answer contains an example how read/write `wchar_t` based streams in `'utf-8'` in a way described in your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522152/python-is-a-dictionary-slow-to-find-frequency-of-each-character/2525617#2525617