# Is there an STL string class that properly handles Unicode?

Tags: c++, unicode, stl, unicode-string

I know all about std::string and std::wstring but they don't seem to fully pay attention to extended character encoding of UTF-8 and UTF-16 (On windows at least).  There is also no support for UTF-32.

So does anyone know of cross-platform drop-in replacement classes that provide full UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 support?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well in C++0x there  are classes std::u32string and std::u16string. GCC already partially supports them, so you can already use them, but streams support for unicode is not yet done [Unicode support in C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704585/unicode-support-in-c0x).

Comment: Hmm I hadn't noticed that in the new standard.  Very interesting.  A big shame that I can't use it on compilers lacking C++0x support (such as the iPhone compiler).  It genuinely shocks me that these classes don't already exist ...

Comment: Interestingly, though, it seems that GCC > 4.4 and VS2010 both support it.  Which is brilliant.  On the major platforms that covers windows, linux and the Android mobile platform.  Clang also states that "many" examples work ...

Comment: @Goz Well not everything is as good as you think. VS2010 supports unicode strings, but it doesn't support unicode string literals. u"Hello" is UTF-16 string literal and U"Hello" is UTF-32 literal. Visual studio don't recognize them. And also as I already said gcc doesn't support input, output streams yet.

Answer (score 11):

And let's not forget the lightweight, very user-friendly, header-only UTF-8 library [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/). Not a drop-in replacement, but can easily be used in conjunction with `std::string` and has no external dependencies.

Comment: This is a nice little library :)

Answer (score 7):

It's not STL, but if you want proper Unicode in C++, then you should take a look at [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Comment: Looks interesting.  Shame there is no STL string support from it though ... it would be perfect in that case ...

Comment: read about it, but after spending some time with DB2, I'd think twice before touching anything coming from IBM. Have you worked with it? Is it good?

Comment: @Goz: I could not agree more, unicode is "standard" enough that we could wish for a string that do more than storing byte sequences...

Answer (score 3):

There is no support of UTF-8 on the STL. As an alternative youo can use [boost codecvt](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/serialization/doc/codecvt.html):

```
//...
// My encoding type
typedef wchar_t ucs4_t;

std::locale old_locale;
std::locale utf8_locale(old_locale,new utf8_codecvt_facet<ucs4_t>);

// Set a New global locale
std::locale::global(utf8_locale);

// Send the UCS-4 data out, converting to UTF-8
{
    std::wstringstream oss;
    oss.imbue(utf8_locale);
    std::copy(ucs4_data.begin(),ucs4_data.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<ucs4_t,ucs4_t>(oss));

    std::wcout << oss.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Its not really a sropin replacement though ;)  Ideally i'd love to see something like std::string8, std::string16 and std::string32 ...

Answer (score 2):

For UTF-8 support, there is the [Glib::ustring](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glibmm/unstable/classGlib_1_1ustring.html) class. It is modeled after `std::string` but is utf-8 aware,e.g. when you are scanning the string with an iterator. It also has some restrictions, e.g. the iterator is always `const`, as replacing a character can change the length of the string and so it can invalidate other iterators.

`ustring` does not automatically converts other encodings to utf-8, `Glib` library has various [conversion functions](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glibmm/unstable/group__CharsetConv.html#ga58f7e4556c436a96c64b186bbc8f7f4c)  for this. You can validate whether the string is a valid utf-8 though.

And also, `ustring` and `std::string` are interchangeable, i.e. `ustring` has a cast operator to std::string so you can pass a `ustring` as a parameter where an `std::string` is expected, and vice versa of course, as `ustring` can be constructed from `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) has QString which uses UTF-16 internally, but has methods for converting to or from std::wstring, UTF-8, Latin1 or locale encoding. There is also the QTextCodec class which can convert QStrings to or from basically anything. But using Qt for just strings seems like an overkill to me.

Comment: Yeah, alas, you are totally right on using it purely for strings.  I like qt though and do use it for quite a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

Also look at http://grigory.info/UTF8Strings.About.html it is UTF8 native.