# Iterative in order over Counter object

Tags: python

I have a Counter object that looks like this:

```
counts = Counter({'foo': 10, 'baz': 5, 'biff': 3, 'bonk': 1})

for k, v in counts.items(): 
    print k, v

    bonk 1
    foo 10
    baz 5
    biff 3
```

What is the best way to iterative over the Counter object by descending frequency of the values? Speed is important. There is an OrderCounter class in the docs, but I was looking for something simpler.

Comment: btw, if speed is important then [`Counter()` might not be the best](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2525617/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Counter.most_common()`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common)

```
>>> counts = Counter({'foo': 10, 'baz': 5, 'biff': 3, 'bonk': 1})
>>> for k, v in counts.most_common():
    print k, v
foo 10
baz 5
biff 3
bonk 1
```