# Fastest way to count three items referenced by one of them (using python)?

Tags: python, hash, dictionary

I have a multi column (13 columns) space separated file (some 5 million+ lines), going like this:

```
 1. W5 403  407 P Y 2 2 PR 22  PNIYR 22222 12.753 13.247
 2. W5 404  408 N V 2 2 PR 22  PIYYR 22222 13.216 13.247
 3. W3 274  276 E G 1 1 EG 11  EPG 121 6.492 6.492
 4. W3 275  277 P R 2 1 PR 21  PGR 211 6.365 7.503
 5. W3 276  278 G Y 1 1 GY 11  GRY 111 5.479 5.479
 6. W3 46  49 G L 1 1 GY 11  GRY 111 5.176 5.176
 7. W4 47  50 D K 1 1 DK 11  DILK 1111 4.893 5.278
 8. W4 48  51 I K 1 1 IK 11  ILKK 1111 4.985 5.552
```

etc., etc.,

I'm interested in 2 of these columns (col 8 & 11) and want to count the number of occurrences of particular pairs (col 8) with the strings that follow (in col 11).

Ex., reference key 'GY' : # of occurrences of '111' : 2 
key 'PR' : # of occurrences of '22222': 2 
key 'DK' : # of occurrences of '1111' :1 
key 'EG' : # of occurrences of '121': 1

I have a dict based basic implementation of it.

```
countshash={}
for l in bigtable:
          cont = l.split()
          if cont[7] not in countshash: countshash[cont[7]] = {}
          if cont[11] not in countshash[cont[7]]: countshash[cont[7]][cont[10]] = 0
          countshash[cont[7]][cont[10]]+= 1;
```

I also have a simple awk based counting (which is super-fast) but was wondering about an
efficient & faster way to do this in python. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: whats the issue with your dict based implementation?

Comment: @tMC: user17177 is asking if there is any faster way of doing it.

Comment: @user17177: Can you post a sample line from `bigtable` (like an actual Python object)?

Comment: related: [Python - Is a dictionary slow to find frequency of each character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522152/python-is-a-dictionary-slow-to-find-frequency-of-each-character)

Comment: @Blender the above table itself is a sample. if you want, can post more lines of it, as an object.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this will help with speed, but you are creating a ton of `defaultdict`-like objects, which I think you can make a bit more readable:

```
from collections import defaultdict

countshash = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for l in bigtable:
    cont = l.split()
    countshash[cont[7]][cont[10]] += 1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(tuple(row.split()[8:12:3]) for row in bigtable)
```

using `itemgetter` is more flexible and may be more efficient than slicing

```
from operator import itemgetter
ig = itemgetter(8, 11)
Counter(ig(row.split()) for row in bigtable)
```

using `imap` can make things a tiny big faster too

```
from itertools import imap
Counter(imap(ig, imap(str.split, bigtable)))
```

Comment: Is slicing really faster than direct index access?

Comment: @sr2222, using `itemgetter` seems faster for me

Answer (score 1):

Well you are doing double lookup. You could just do `countshash[(cont[7],count[10])]+=1`, this could be faster, but depends on how python implements it. Memory footprint should be slightly bigger.

Something simple like:

```
countshash=defaultdict(int)
for l in bigtable:
          cont = l.split()
          countshash[(cont[7],cont[10])]+= 1;
```

Comment: And as long as you can guarantee that you can avoid name confusion (ex never having PR1/111 and PR/1111).

Comment: agree, but you can still replace order if it solves the problem.

Comment: Or you could just drop the strings in to a tuple and use that as the dict key instead of concatenating the strings.  That would probably make your life easier if/when you want to read data back out of this structure too.

Comment: By the way, [here](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/) is an article how python dicts are implemented.

Comment: Interesting.  Is there a way to optimize performance by explicitly setting start size of the hash array?  It seems you would need a custom cType for that...

Comment: `d={}; d['a'] += 1` raises KeyError. You could use [`defaultdict`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12063356/4279) to fix it. Also `()` are unnecessary to create a 2-item tuple.

Comment: @offlinehacker, as pointed out the catch in the above code is that dict needs to be initialized first with Keys. defaultdict works well.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

countshash = defaultdict(int)
for l in bigtable:
    cont = l.split()
    countshash[cont[7], cont[10]] += 1
```

Comment: based on the simple tests i did, the speed for this seem comparable to the basic dict based method whereas the above lambda implementation is a tad faster. needs more thorough profiling though.

Comment: @user17177: It is surprising. This is why profiling with your own data, in your environment is useful.