# Why is collections.Counter much slower than ''.count?

Tags: python, performance, counter

I have a simple task: To count how many times every letter occurs in a string. I've used a `Counter()` for it, but on one forum I saw information that using `dict()` / `Counter()` is much slower than using `string.count()` for every letter. I thought that it would interate through the string only once, and the `string.count()` solution would have to iterate through it four times (in this case). Why is `Counter()` so slow?

```
>>> timeit.timeit('x.count("A");x.count("G");x.count("C");x.count("T")', setup="x='GAAAAAGTCGTAGGGTTCCTTCACTCGAGGAATGCTGCGACAGTAAAGGAGGCCACGTGGTTGAGAGTTCCTAAGCATTCGTATGTACACCCGGACTCGATGCACTCAAACGTGCTTAAGGGTAAAGAAGGTCGAGAGGTATACTGGGGCACTCCCCTTAGAATTATATCTTGGTCAACTACAATATGGATGGAAATTCTAAGCCGAAAACGACCCGCTAGCGGATTGTGTATGTATCACAACGGTTTCGGTTCATACGCAAAATCATCCCATTTCAAGGCCACTCAAGGACATGACGCCGTGCAACTCCGAGGACATCCCTCAGCGATTGATGCAACCTGGTCATCTAATAATCCTTAGAACGGATGTGCCCTCTACTGGGAGAGCCGGCTAGACTGGCATCTCGCGTTGTTCGTACGAGCTCCGGGCGCCCGGGCGGTGTACGTTGATGTACAGCCTAAGAGCTTTCCACCTATGCTACGAACTAATTTCCCGTCCATCGTTCCTCGGACTGAGGTCAAAGTAACCCGGAAGTACATGGATCAGATACACTCACAGTCCCCTTTAATGACTGAGCTGGACGCTATTGATTGCTTTATAAGTGTTATGGTGAACTCGAAGACTTAGCTAGGAATTTCGCTATACCCGGGTAATGAGCTTAATACCTCACAGCATGTACGCTCTGAATATATGTAGCGATGCTAGCGGAACGTAAGCGTGAGCGTTATGCAGGGCTCCGCACCTCGTGGCCACTCGCCCAATGCCCGAGTTTTTGAGCAATGCCATGCCCTCCAGGTGAAGCGTGCTGAATATGTTCCGCCTCCGCACACCTACCCTACGGGCCTTACGCCATAGCTGAGGATACGCGAGTTGGTTAGCGATTACGTCATTCCAGGTGGTCGTTC'", number=10000)
0.07911698750407936
>>> timeit.timeit('Counter(x)', setup="from collections import Counter;x='GAAAAAGTCGTAGGGTTCCTTCACTCGAGGAATGCTGCGACAGTAAAGGAGGCCACGTGGTTGAGAGTTCCTAAGCATTCGTATGTACACCCGGACTCGATGCACTCAAACGTGCTTAAGGGTAAAGAAGGTCGAGAGGTATACTGGGGCACTCCCCTTAGAATTATATCTTGGTCAACTACAATATGGATGGAAATTCTAAGCCGAAAACGACCCGCTAGCGGATTGTGTATGTATCACAACGGTTTCGGTTCATACGCAAAATCATCCCATTTCAAGGCCACTCAAGGACATGACGCCGTGCAACTCCGAGGACATCCCTCAGCGATTGATGCAACCTGGTCATCTAATAATCCTTAGAACGGATGTGCCCTCTACTGGGAGAGCCGGCTAGACTGGCATCTCGCGTTGTTCGTACGAGCTCCGGGCGCCCGGGCGGTGTACGTTGATGTACAGCCTAAGAGCTTTCCACCTATGCTACGAACTAATTTCCCGTCCATCGTTCCTCGGACTGAGGTCAAAGTAACCCGGAAGTACATGGATCAGATACACTCACAGTCCCCTTTAATGACTGAGCTGGACGCTATTGATTGCTTTATAAGTGTTATGGTGAACTCGAAGACTTAGCTAGGAATTTCGCTATACCCGGGTAATGAGCTTAATACCTCACAGCATGTACGCTCTGAATATATGTAGCGATGCTAGCGGAACGTAAGCGTGAGCGTTATGCAGGGCTCCGCACCTCGTGGCCACTCGCCCAATGCCCGAGTTTTTGAGCAATGCCATGCCCTCCAGGTGAAGCGTGCTGAATATGTTCCGCCTCCGCACACCTACCCTACGGGCCTTACGCCATAGCTGAGGATACGCGAGTTGGTTAGCGATTACGTCATTCCAGGTGGTCGTTC'", number=10000)
2.1727447831030844
>>> 2.1727447831030844 / 0.07911698750407936
27.462430656767047
>>>
```

Comment: It isn't algorithmically - `x.count()` means you loop once per item you check, the `Counter()` only loops once. Presumably the overhead in this case is higher than the saving.

Comment: related: [Python - Is a dictionary slow to find frequency of each character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522152/python-is-a-dictionary-slow-to-find-frequency-of-each-character)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Counter()` allows you to count any hashable objects, not just substrings. Both solutions are `O(n)`-time. Your measurements show that the overhead of iterating and hashing individual characters by `Counter()` is greater than running `s.count()` 4 times.

`Counter()` *can* use C helper to count elements but it seems it doesn't special case strings and uses general algorithm applicable for any other iterable i.e., [processing a single character involves multiple Python C API calls to advance the iterator, get previous value (a lookup in the hash table), increment counter, set new value (a lookup in the hash table)](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8a6068ec220e/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#l1680):

```c
    while (1) {
        key = PyIter_Next(it);
        if (key == NULL)
            break;
        oldval = PyObject_GetItem(mapping, key);
        if (oldval == NULL) {
            if (!PyErr_Occurred() || !PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_KeyError))
                break;
            PyErr_Clear();
            Py_INCREF(one);
            newval = one;
        } else {
            newval = PyNumber_Add(oldval, one);
            Py_DECREF(oldval);
            if (newval == NULL)
                break;
        }
        if (PyObject_SetItem(mapping, key, newval) == -1)
            break;
        Py_CLEAR(newval);
        Py_DECREF(key);
    }
```

Compare it to [`FASTSEARCH()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8a6068ec220e/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h#l88) overhead for bytestrings:

```c
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (s[i] == p[0]) {
           count++;
           if (count == maxcount)
              return maxcount;
        }
    return count;
```

Answer (score 8):

The `Counter` class inherits from `dict`, while `string.count` is the following C-implementation (CPython 3.3):

```
/* stringlib: count implementation */

#ifndef STRINGLIB_FASTSEARCH_H
#error must include "stringlib/fastsearch.h" before including this module
#endif


Py_LOCAL_INLINE(Py_ssize_t)
STRINGLIB(count)(const STRINGLIB_CHAR* str, Py_ssize_t str_len,
                const STRINGLIB_CHAR* sub, Py_ssize_t sub_len,
                Py_ssize_t maxcount)
{
    Py_ssize_t count;

    if (str_len < 0)
        return 0; /* start > len(str) */
    if (sub_len == 0)
        return (str_len < maxcount) ? str_len + 1 : maxcount;

    count = FASTSEARCH(str, str_len, sub, sub_len, maxcount, FAST_COUNT);

    if (count < 0)
        return 0; /* no match */

    return count;
}
```

Guess, which one is faster? :)