# Python FizzBuzz

Tags: python, python-2.7, fizzbuzz

I have been given this question to do in Python:

Take in a list of numbers from the user and run FizzBuzz on that list.

When you loop through the list remember the rules:

1. If the number is divisible by both 3 and 5 print `FizzBuzz`
2. If it's only divisible by 3 print `Fizz`
3. If it's only divisible by 5 print `Buzz`
4. Otherwise just print the number

Also remember elif!

I have the following script created, but it gives me an error at if `n%3=True`

```
n = input()
if n % 3 = True:
    print("Fizz")
else if n % 5 = True:
    print("Buzz")
elif print n
```

Can anyone help? Thank you very much!

Comment: maybe you mean : `n%3==0`

Comment: Ah, yes, the famous FizzBuzz test [designed to determine whether an applicant actually knows how to code](http://imranontech.com/2007/01/24/using-fizzbuzz-to-find-developers-who-grok-coding/).

Comment: The best part is how you remembered `elif` only after writing `else if`, even though the problem statement told you to remember it.

Comment: There are many Python tutorials that will help you to get a basic understanding of the language. For example https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/ is the official introduction.

Answer (score 8):

A few issues with your code here. The first issue is that, for comparison, you should be using `==`, not `=`, which is for *assignment*.

The second issue is that you want to check that the remainder of the divisions (which is what the modulo operator calculates) is *zero*, not that it's *true*, which doesn't really make sense.

You should be using `elif` for "otherwise if..." and `else` for "otherwise." And you need to fix the formatting of your `else` clause.

You want:

```
n=input()
if n%3 == 0:
    print("Fizz")
elif n%5 == 0:
    print ("Buzz")
else:
    print n
```

Finally, your code does not meet the spec:

> 1) If the number is divisible by both 3 and 5 print "FizzBuzz"

The above will not do this. This part I'm going to leave to you because I'm not here to solve the assignment for you :)

Comment: The OP forgot `:` in the `else` statement. ;)

Comment: @SukritKalra And that!

Comment: Also, since the OP is using `print n`, I'm assuming he's on 2.x where `True == 1` and `False == 0`. Not a great way to write the code, but nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @SukritKalra In that case, he still has it the wrong way around.

Answer (score 6):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/103081/1327325)

> FizzBuzz: For integers up to and including 100, prints FizzBuzz if the integer is divisible by 3 and 5 (15); Fizz if it's divisible by 3 (and not 5); Buzz if it's divisible by 5 (and not 3); and the integer otherwise.

```
def FizzBuzz():
    for i in range(1,101):
        print {
            3 : "Fizz",
            5 : "Buzz",
            15 : "FizzBuzz"}.get(15*(not i%15) or
                                 5*(not i%5 ) or
                                 3*(not i%3 ), '{}'.format(i))
```

The `.get()` method works wonders here.

Operates as follows

For all integers from 1 to 100 (101 is NOT included),
print the value of the dictionary key that we call via get according to these rules.

"Get the first non-False item in the `get` call, or return the integer as a string."

When checking for a `True` value, thus a value we can lookup, Python evaluates 0 to `False`. If i mod 15 = 0, that's False, we would go to the next one.

Therefore we `NOT` each of the 'mods' (aka remainder), so that if the mod == 0, which == False, we get a True statement. We multiply `True` by the dictionary key which returns the dictionary key (i.e. `3*True == 3`)

When the integer it not divisible by 3, 5 or 15, then we fall to the default clause of printing the int `'{}'.format(i)` just inserts i into that string - as a string.

Some of the output

Fizz
79
Buzz
Fizz
82
83
Fizz
Buzz
86
Fizz
88
89
FizzBuzz
91
92
Fizz
94
Buzz
Fizz
97
98
Fizz
Buzz

Answer (score 4):

`n % 3` (or `n %` any number) does not evaluate to `True` or `False`, it's not a Boolean expression.  `n % 3 == 0` on the other hand, does.

As an aside, what happens when `n % 3 == 0` and `n % 5 == 0` both evaluate to `True`?

Comment: @geoffspear is right, they are subclasses of `int` (can be checked with `isinstance(True, int)`). `True+3` is `4`, and `False*5` is `0` in Python. So checking divisibility by 3 can be done by `n%3 == 0` or `n%3 == False`, even though the latter would not be intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I did it using generators.
Explanations are added as comments.

```py
# the factors to check for, along with its
# associated text data.
FACTORS = {
    3 : "Fizz",
    5 : "Buzz",
}


def fizzbuzz(start, stop):
    """FizzBuzz printer"""
    for i in range(start, stop+1):
        string = ""  # build string

        # iterate through all factors
        for j, dat in FACTORS.items():
            # test for divisibility
            if i % j == 0:
                # add data to string if divisible
                string += dat

        if not string:
            # if string's length is 0, it means,
            # all the factors returned non-zero
            # modulus, so return only the number
            yield str(i)
        else:
            # factor had returned modulo as 0,
            # return the string
            yield string


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for each in fizzbuzz(1, 100):
        print(each)
```

This version has the advantage of not depending on any extra factor checks.

Answer (score 2):

one of the shortest answers i have found is

```
c=1
while c<101:print((c%3<1)*'Fizz'+(c%5<1)*'Buzz'or c);c+=1
```

61 characters

Answer (score 1):

Make it universal for any integer, positive or negative. 
Also make it easily expandable to other keywords for any integer by creating a dictionary of keywords.

```
def checkdict(divdict, i):
    out = ""
    for key in divdict:
        if key != 0:
            if i%key==0:
                out+=divdict[key]
        if key == 0 and i == 0:
                out+=divdict[key]
    if out == "":
        out = i
    print(out)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mydict = {3:"Fizz",5:"Buzz"}
    for i in range(-50,50):
        checkdict(mydict, i)
```

Comment: Actually the output of this code is not well-defined: Iterating through a has no predictable order (therefore for 15 it might create 'FizzBuzz' or 'FuzzBizz') and I think this is a good example for over-engineering: It is much more general than required and adds much complexity; on the other side also the naming is not very well.

Answer (score 1):

```
def check(num):
    finalWord = ''
    for k,v in numWordDict.items():
        if num % k == 0:
            finalWord += v

    if not finalWord:
        return num
    else: 
        return finalWord

def FizzLoop(start=0, stop=10, step=1):
    for i in range(start, stop, step):
        print(check(i))


numWordDict = {3:'fizz', 6:'buzz', 5:'fiver'}

FizzLoop(0, 10)
print("----------")
FizzLoop(0, 50, 5)
```

Comment: Hello user12616353! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Next time you gonna add an answer, try add some explanation to it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Numbers = [3, 5]
Labels = ["Fizz", "Buzz"] 

for i in range(1, 101):
    Output ="" 
    for j in range (len(Numbers) ) : 
        if i % Numbers[j] == 0:
            Output = Output + Labels[j]     
              
        if Output =="" :                           
             print(i) 
        else:
             print(Output)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix @Seljuk Gülcan . Ok so with this script it is very easy to just add more numbers and labels as I would hope is very easy to see.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing fancy, using a while loop to achieve the same result:

```
x,xx = 1,100
xy,xz = 3,5
mylist = []

while x <= xx:
    y = (x/xy).is_integer()
    z = (x/xz).is_integer()

    if y and z:
        mylist.append("fizzbuzz")
    elif y:
        mylist.append("fizz")
    elif z:
        mylist.append("buzz")
    else:
        mylist.append(x)
    x+=1

print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def fizz_buzz(input):
  if (input % 3 == 0) and (input % 5 == 0):
     return "FizzBuzz"
  if input % 3 == 0:
     return "Fizz"
  if input % 5 == 0:
     return "Buzz"
  return input


print(fizz_buzz(15))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the 1 liner code (list comprehension) code below. Hope this is easy to understand . if it's not please do let me know. I will elaborate.

```
N = 10 #user_input
print(list(map(lambda n: "Fizz" if (n % 3 == 0) else ( "Buzz" if (n % 5 == 0) else n),[i for i in range(1,N+1)])))
```