# How to convert string to dictionary, and count the number of each word

Tags: python, string, dictionary, python-3.x

I am just wondering how i would convert a string, such as "hello there hi there", and turn it into a dictionary, then using this dictionary, i want to count the number of each word in the dictionary, and return it in alphabetic order. So in this case it would return:

```
[('hello', 1), ('hi', 1), ('there', 2)]
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Given a string `"hi, there!"` how would you split it into words? Given a string `维基百科` how would you split it into words?

Answer (score 14):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> text = "hello there hi there"
>>> sorted(Counter(text.split()).items())
[('hello', 1), ('hi', 1), ('there', 2)]
```

> [`class collections.Counter([iterable-or-mapping])`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)
>
> A `Counter` is a `dict` subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values. Counts are allowed to be any integer value including zero or negative counts. The `Counter` class is similar to bags or multisets in other languages.

Answer (score 4):

jamylak did fine with `Counter`. this is a solution without importing `Counter`:

```
text = "hello there hi there"
dic = dict()
for w in text.split():
    if w in dic.keys():
        dic[w] = dic[w]+1
    else:
        dic[w] = 1
```

gives

```
>>> dic
{'hi': 1, 'there': 2, 'hello': 1}
```

Comment: I would suggest `dic[w] = dic.get(w, 0) + 1` instead of the `if else`

Comment: 1. you could use `{}` instead of `dict()` 2. `if w in dic:` works as is without `dic.keys()` 3. `dic[w] += 1` instead of `dic[w] = dic[w] + 1`. If you don't want to use Counter; you could use `dic = collections.defaultdict(int)` and remove `if/else`. Here's [a performance comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2522152/4279)