# Python list sort by size of group

Tags: python, python-2.6, python-itertools, sorting

I have a group of items that are labeled like `item_labels = [('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 1), ('d', 3), ('e', 2), ('f', 3)]`

I want to sort them by the size of group. e.g., label 3 has size 3 and label 2 has size 2 in the above example.

I tried using a combination of `groupby` and `sorted` but didn't work.

```
In [162]: sil = sorted(item_labels, key=op.itemgetter(1))

In [163]: sil
Out[163]: [('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('e', 2), ('a', 3), ('d', 3), ('f', 3)]

In [164]: g = itt.groupby(sil,)
Display all 465 possibilities? (y or n)

In [164]: g = itt.groupby(sil, key=op.itemgetter(1))

In [165]: for k, v in g:
   .....:     print k, list(v)
   .....:
   .....:
1 [('c', 1)]
2 [('b', 2), ('e', 2)]
3 [('a', 3), ('d', 3), ('f', 3)]

In [166]: sg = sorted(g, key=lambda x: len(list(x[1])))

In [167]: sg
Out[167]: [] # not exactly know why I got an empty list here
```

I can always write some tedious for-loop to do this, but I would rather find something more elegant. Any suggestion? If there are libraries that are useful I would happy to use that. e.g., `pandas`, `scipy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python2.7 and above, use Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(y for _, y in item_labels)
item_labels.sort(key=lambda t : c[t[1]])
```

In python2.6, for our purpose, this `Counter` constructor can be implemented using `defaultdict` (as suggested by @perreal) this way:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def Counter(x):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for v in x: d[v]+=1
    return d
```

Since we are working with numbers only, and assuming the numbers are as low as those in your example, we can actually use a list (which will be compatible with even older version of Python):

```
def Counter(x):
    lst = list(x)
    d = [0] * (max(lst)+1)
    for v in lst: d[v]+=1
    return d
```

Without counter, you can simply do this:

```
item_labels.sort(key=lambda t : len([x[1] for x in item_labels if x[1]==t[1] ]))
```

It is slower, but reasonable over short lists.

---

The reason you've got an empty list is that `g` is a generator. You can only iterate over it once.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using python 2.6 so can't really use `Counter`.

Comment: Thanks. This line `item_labels.sort(key=lambda t : c[t[0]])` should be `item_labels.sort(key=lambda t : c[t[1]])`?

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import operator
l=[('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('e', 2), ('a', 3), ('d', 3), ('f', 3)]
d=defaultdict(int)
for p in l: d[p[1]] += 1
print [ p for i in sorted(d.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
        for p in l if p[1] == i[1] ]
```

Comment: You are effectively implementing a `Counter` using `defaultdict`

Comment: @Elazar: Which is actually faster than default dict in many cases. Try it. +1

Comment: @drewk: [`defaultdict` can be faster than `Counter`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2525617/4279) though it doesn't  matter in this case

Answer (score 2):

`itertools.groupby` returns an iterator, so this for loop: `for k, v in g:` actually consumed that iterator.

```
>>> it = iter([1,2,3])
>>> for x in it:pass
>>> list(it)          #iterator already consumed by the for-loop
[]
```

**code:**

```
>>> lis = [('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 1), ('d', 3), ('e', 2), ('f', 3)]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> lis.sort(key = itemgetter(1) )
>>> new_lis = [list(v) for k,v in groupby(lis, key = itemgetter(1) )]
>>> new_lis.sort(key = len)
>>> new_lis
[[('c', 1)], [('b', 2), ('e', 2)], [('a', 3), ('d', 3), ('f', 3)]]
```

To get a flattened list use `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list( chain.from_iterable(new_lis))
[('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('e', 2), ('a', 3), ('d', 3), ('f', 3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Same as [@perreal's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17285748/4279) and [@Elazar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17285592/4279) answers, but with better names:

```
from collections import defaultdict

size = defaultdict(int)
for _, group_id in item_labels:
   size[group_id] += 1

item_labels.sort(key=lambda (_, group_id): size[group_id])
print item_labels
# -> [('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('e', 2), ('a', 3), ('d', 3), ('f', 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
example=[('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 1), ('d', 3), ('e', 2), ('f', 3)]

out={}
for t in example:
    out.setdefault(t[1],[]).append(t)

print sorted(out.values(),key=len)
```

Prints:

```
[[('c', 1)], [('b', 2), ('e', 2)], [('a', 3), ('d', 3), ('f', 3)]]
```

If you want a flat list:

```
print [l for s in sorted(out.values(),key=len) for l in s]
[('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('e', 2), ('a', 3), ('d', 3), ('f', 3)]
```