# Python-read a file from a defined variable

Tags: python, file, input

I want to a user to `input` a file name to be read (for example: `text.txt`) in Python, but it reads as string and not file type.

```
r=(input("insert the name of the file"))
  File= open(r,'r')
  data=File.read()
  data.split()
  print(data)
```

Comment: Wait, what? I don't understand what you are asking at all. Of course it reads as a string, why would it do anything else?

Comment: Your code does exactly what you want it to right now. What's the issue you're having?

Comment: _and not file type_: What do you _expect_ it to do based on the file type?

Comment: maybe you want to read

Comment: Indentation is a bit off and there are a pair of extra () that's not needed. Except from that, the code is correct.

Comment: The only thing that I can see wrong with this code is that `data.split()` does nothing. I think you mean `data = data.split()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### New hotness

EDIT: as per the comments on my answer, OP is looking to build a `dict` containing `{word:wordcount}` for all words in a file (whitespace separated).

There's one REALLY GREAT way to do this, but it doesn't really teach you anything, so I'll show you the slow way to do it first, then include the optimal solution afterwards.

```
wordcountdict = dict()

r = input("filename: ")
with open(r, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        for word in infile.split(): # split on whitespace
            try:
                wordcountdict[word.lower()] += 1
                # try adding one to the word in the counter
            except KeyError:
                wordcountdict[word.lower()] = 1
                # If the word isn't in the dict already, set it to 1
```

Now you may want to filter out some common words (`"at"`, `"I"`, `"then"` etc), in which case you can build a blacklist of them (something like `blacklist = ['at', 'i', 'then']`) and do `if word.lower() in blacklist: continue` inside the `for word in infile.split()` and before the `try/except` block. That will test if the word is in the blacklist, and skip the rest of that execution if it is.

Now I promised you a GREAT way to do this, and that's with `collections.Counter`. It's a dictionary specifically created to count elements in a list. There are faster ways to count words, but nothing cleaner in Python (imo). You check out timings on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522152/python-is-a-dictionary-slow-to-find-frequency-of-each-character)

```
from collections import Counter

wordcountdict = Counter()
r = input("filename: ")
with open(r, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        wordcountdict += Counter( map(str.lower,line.split()) )
```

If you've never used imports from `collections`, or the `map` function, this is going to be very arcane which is why I didn't put it first! :).

Basically: `collections.Counter` takes as an argument an iterable, and counts all elements in the iterable (so `Counter([1,1,2,3,4,4,4]) == {1:2, 2:1, 3:1, 4:3}). You can add them and it creates new keys where they're unique and adds values where they're not.

`map(callable, iterable)` runs `callable` with an argument of each element of the iterable, and returns a `map` object (it's a `list` in Python2) that is itself iterable (so `map(str.lower, ["ThIS", "Has", "UppEr", "aNd", "LOWERcase"])` gives you a map object that you can iterate through to get `["this","has","upper","and","lowercase"]` since `str.lower` was called on all of it).

When we combine the two, we're feeding `collections.Counter` a `map` object that's lowercased each individual word in `line.split()`, then adding it to an initially-empty `Counter` that's being used as an accumulator. *Capisce?*

### Old and busted

It's very unclear what your problem is with the code, so I'll just throw out some knowledge for you and hope something sticks.

```
r = input("insert the name of the file")
# this will be a string from the user, containing the file name, e.g.
# r == "text.txt"
# this is normal, because you pass `open` a filename, not a file object

File = open(r, "r")
# this makes File a file object that's pointed at the file name given from
# the user, opened for reading.

data = File.read()
# this sets data equal to the string containing the entire text in File
# This is usually NOT what you want to do, but without further explanation,
# I'll leave it be

data.split()
# this isn't an in-place operation, so you built a list out of the string
# data, split on newlines, then threw it away since you didn't assign it to
# anything.

print(data)
# prints your original data variable, because remember data.split() is not
# in-place, you'd have to do data = data.split(), but that's the wrong way
# to do that anyway....
```

Here's what I THINK you want to do...

```
filename = input("insert the name of the file: ")
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    data = infile.readlines()
```

This uses a context manager (`with`) instead of `File = open(filename)`, because that's a better practice. It basically frees you from having to type `File.close()` after you're done with it, and also accounts for the fact that Things Can Go Wrong while you're working with files, so if for whatever reason your code throws an exception and doesn't GET to your `File.close()`, it still closes the file object once it leaves the `with` block.

It also uses `.readlines()` instead of `.read().split()`, which is literally the same thing. This is still probably NOT what you're trying to do (in most cases you want to just iterate through a file rather than dump all its data into memory) but without more context, I can't help you further.

It also follows PEP8's naming convention, where `Capitalizednames` are classes. `File` is not a class, it's a file object, so I named it `infile` instead. I usually use `in_` and `out` for filenames, but YMMV.

If you comment in what you're trying to do with the file, I can write some specific code for you.

Comment: It would be better to do `read().splitlines()` as `readlines()` leaves the annoying newline character `'\n'` that Python gets whilst scanning the file.

Comment: @AlexThornton `list(map(strip,map(splitlines,''.join([char for char in infile.read()]))))` for more obfuscation :)

Comment: Very good explanation!
But what i want to do is to recieve a file and count the number of words in that file, and put them in a dicitionary with {word,numberoftimes}.
Im new at python so im still learning

Comment: @user3448350 I'll edit, but you should put that in the question so we can reopen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't mind taking a shot in the dark.  But it would help if you posted one of the files to be read.  and you need to account for the person now knowing which file they should type and what happens when they don't type what you think they will type.

```
r = raw_input('type the name of the file: ')
with open(r,'r') as myfile:
    for data in myfile:
        print(data.split())
```

Comment: A concern here, `data` in OP's code doesn't mean `data` in your code. Your `data` is just one line of the file. Not bad by any means, just may be confusing for OP

Comment: Good point.  It was more instructional on how to use/format data.