# counting the frequency of a letter in a string

Tags: python-3.x

so far this is what i have and this and this will just print out a list with the count of each letter in the string. it only checks for lowercase letters.

```
`S="""Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent a new nation
Now we are engaged in a great civil war
"""
lowlet = S.lower()
L_count = [0]*26
total_count = 0
alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
i = 0
while i < len(lowlet):
    if lowlet[i] in alpha:
        L_count[i][ord(lowlet[i]) - 97] += 1
        total_count += 1
    i += 1
print('total count of letters:',total_count)'
```

now im giving this algorithm but i cant put it into code and i cant use a for loop  i have to use a while loop 
Initialize a list, L_freq.
For each element, count, in L_counts
    Find the letter corresponding to this count
    Insert in L_freq, the list: [count, letter]

Comment: here are [multiple ways to count frequencies of characters in a text](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2525617/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it a requirement that it be a list? I feel like a dictionary would be easier to handle

```
sentence = s.lower()
counts = { letter: sentence.count(letter) for letter in alpha }
print(counts)
```

this will print like:
`{'a': 5, 'b': 2}`

Comment: yes its a requirement what i was thinking was a tuple in a list. yea most diffidently a dictionary would be easier. Thats why im having so much trouble with all this restrictions.

Comment: Have you considered using a `collections.Counter`?

Comment: i haven't actually got to that topic yet but i just looked them up and it seems like a good idea.